# Why do I got error dialog when opening Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

[image: error dialog]
When opening Eclipse, a dialog opens and here is the message displayed in the dialog:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/bin/java
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /opt/marseclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-launcher /opt/marseclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /opt/marseclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417/eclipse_1612.so
-startup /opt/marseclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata c78010
-data /root/workspace2
-application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild
-import /root/workspace2/ut
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /opt/marseclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
```

Please guide!

Comment: can not open the image link.Is it something related to java path?

Comment: I'm using Mars.2 and install a CDT(seems to be helios ver.). And call "eclipse -data myworkspace -nosplash -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -import myproject" and "eclipse -data myworkspace" using Runtime.getRuntime.exec() in Eclipse to open another Eclipse workbenrch. Then the dialog opens, but what's confused me is that the new workbench seems to be work well.

Answer (score 0):

okay so there seems to be a memory problem.You can go to config file and increase the **Xms256m** size to 512 or 1024 which ever works for you.And heap memory ie **Xms256m** depends on your physical memory of OS.So change accordingly.

You can change it by going to run configuration you want to customizeand open the tab Arguments and add -Xmx or Xms in the VM arguments section

Comment: Didn't work for me...there's probably something else that's wrong with my set up...

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself. I run eclipse twice (first time to import project to new workbench, second time to open the new workbench) from the first workbench by call Runtime.getRuntime.exec(). I forgot to do process1.waitFor(), so the new workbench intended to be run twice at the same time, this is the root cause.